# pygame image wont appear

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

The app2 image should slide in from the right but it doesn't. Both images are 1920x1080. How can I fix this?

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import*
number=1
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1920,1080))
app1=pygame.image.load("app1.jpg").convert()
app2=pygame.image.load("app2.jpg").convert()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
app1x=0
app2x=1920
loop=True
while loop:
    screen.fill( (0,0,0) )
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_RIGHT:
                print ("right")
                number=number+1
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            print("l")
            loop=False
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    screen.blit(app1, (app1x,0))
    if number==1:
        screen.blit(app1, (app1x,0))
    if number==2:
        if app2x==0:
            print ("d")
        else:
        app2x=app2x-1
        app1x=app1x-1
clock.tick(20)
pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Try doing `pygame.display.update()` just after `screen.blit(app1, (app1x,0))` .

Answer (score 0):

You are only updating a portion of the screen, along with the clock not being inside of the while loop. Here's an example using your code:

```
    while loop:
        screen.fill( (0,0,0) )
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==KEYDOWN:
                if event.key==K_RIGHT:
                    print ("right")
                    number=number+1
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                print("l")
                loop=False
        screen.blit(app1, (app1x,0))
        if number==1:
            screen.blit(app1, (app1x,0))
        if number==2:
            if app2x==0:
                print ("d")
            else:
                app2x=app2x-1
                app1x=app1x-1
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(20)
    pygame.quit()
```

Also, notice how I moved `pygame.quit()` after the entire `while` loop. This makes it so when `loop` is false and finishes, pygame will also exit. Moving `pygame.quit()` is just to clean the code up a slight amount, and doesn't impact the code significantly.

Cheers!